# Find changes from an audit table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, audit

I have data in an audit table like below. [Fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/08d90/1), [Fiddle 2](http://rextester.com/JKJNHO97527)

[image: Audit Table]

I need to get updated columns and data details from this table.

Expected Results is:

> Employee Name : from Jone to Jhone
>
> Employee Age : from 25 to 20
>
> Employee Name : from Jhonny to Jone, Employee Age : from 18 to 25

How could I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

When a record get updated, I am inserting two rows in to audit table. First record as `Old(auditDataState)` with data before the update and Second record as `New(auditDataState)` with updated data.

So each update has two records in audit table as **Old** and **New** with old and new values.

I need to get updated data from the audit table based on `updateColumns` in audit table.(I am storing what columns get updated in updateColumns column).

I don't need to first row to be `Employee Name : from Jone to Jhone`. Just need to identify updated values.

Comment: Are you expecting the value of the first column, from SQL, for the first row to be `'Employee Name : from Jone to Jhone'`? That's not going to be easy. Especially as you're mixing data types later on (I assume `empAge` is a `int`). You would be far better providing a dataset with both values (old and new) and using your application to do the display format. This is an awful task to do in your DBMS.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the reply. Please check the updated question. I don't need to  first row to be `Employee Name : from Jone to Jhone`. Just need to identify updated values. Then I can do the display format.

Comment: You don't say which version you are using. From 2016 onwards, temporal tables are ideally suited for what you require.

Comment: Looking at the data you have supplied, as well, all the changes happened at the same time. How do we determine which "new" row is related to which "old" row?

Comment: Also, how generic does this solution need to be?  As your `updateColumns` value doesn't correspond to the actual column names being updated, the mapping will either need to be manual or each potential data column will need to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide the result as specified in your question, though it is far from a sensible or scalable solution.  If at all possible, I would recommend you completely revisit your change auditing:

```
declare @EmpAudit table (
      empID int
    , empName varchar(50)
    , empAge int
    , auditDataState varchar(50)
    , auditDMLAction varchar(50)
    , auditUser varchar(50)
    , auditDateTime datetime
    , updateColumns varchar(50)
);

insert into @EmpAudit values
      (1, 'Alex', 22, 'New', 'Insert','c@a.com',getdate(),''),
      (2, 'Jhonny', 18, 'New', 'Insert','c@a.com',getdate()-0.5,''),

      (2, 'Jhonny', 18, 'Old', 'Update','b@a.com',getdate()-1,'Employee Name, Employee Age'),
      (2, 'Jone', 25, 'New', 'Update','b@a.com',getdate()-1.5,'Employee Name, Employee Age'),

      (2, 'Jone', 25, 'Old', 'Update','a@a.com',getdate()-2,'Employee Age'),
      (2, 'Jone', 30, 'New', 'Update','a@a.com',getdate()-2.5,'Employee Age'),

      (2, 'Jone', 30, 'Old', 'Update','a@a.com',getdate()-3,'Employee Age'),
      (2, 'Jone', 20, 'New', 'Update','a@a.com',getdate()-3.5,'Employee Age'),

      (2, 'Jone', 20, 'Old', 'Update','a@a.com',getdate()-4,'Employee Name'),
      (2, 'Jhone', 20, 'New', 'Update','a@a.com',getdate()-4.5,'Employee Name');

with d as
(
    select empID
            ,empName
            ,empAge
            ,auditDataState
            ,auditDMLAction
            ,auditUser
            ,auditDateTime
            ,updateColumns
            ,row_number() over (partition by empID order by auditDateTime) as rn
    from @EmpAudit
)
select case when o.empName <> n.empName then 'Employee Name : from ' + o.empName + ' to ' + n.empName else '' end
      +case when charindex(',',o.UpdateColumns) > 0 then ', ' else '' end
      +case when o.empAge <> n.empAge then 'Employee Age : from ' + cast(o.empAge as varchar(3)) + ' to ' + cast(n.empAge as varchar(3)) else '' end as Change
from d as o
    join d as n
        on o.empID = n.empID
            and o.updateColumns = n.updateColumns
            and o.rn = n.rn+1
            and n.auditDataState = 'New'
where o.auditDataState = 'Old';
```

Output:

```
Change
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Employee Name : from Jone to Jhone
Employee Age : from 30 to 20
Employee Age : from 25 to 30
Employee Name : from Jhonny to Jone, Employee Age : from 18 to 25
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the answer what I was looking for. Btw, there is an issue with situation like this. http://rextester.com/HNVGB67216

Comment: @Bishan  No worries :)  If this was the answer you required, please mark it as such for the benefit of other Stack Overflow users.

Comment: Yeah. This is the answer I was looking for. Btw, still not return correct data in situations like in this example. http://rextester.com/HNVGB67216

Comment: @Bishan  Of course there is an issue there, you have not provided enough information within your change auditing process to specify the order of the changes.  This is why I recommend you revisit your entire process.

Comment: It's Old = `30`, New = `20`

Comment: Which is then reverted back to `30` at - according to your data - exactly the same time.  How on earth is the query script supposed to know which happened first?

Comment: @Bishan  Assuming your `auditDateTime` column actually holds the same value for each `Old` and `New` pair (as this would be sensible...) I have amended my query to account for this.

Comment: Oops sorry. My bad. Here is the new one http://rextester.com/ICOYNS6223

Comment: Actually `auditDateTime` column values for `Old` and `New` has difference in milliseconds.

Comment: @Bishan  Why?  Surely you know you are going to `insert` an `Old` *and* a `New` row for each change so why are you not using the same `DateTime`?  Also, your new sample data still has the same `DateTime` values, so I am not sure what your *Oops sorry. My bad. Here is the new one* is actually referring to.

Comment: @Bishan Either way, I have edited my script to account for the difference in `auditDateTime` values.